# Visual Studio breaks Visual Inheritance

Tags: winforms, inheritance, visual-studio-2015, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I have made a `FormBase`, from which I inherit a `FomBaseList` and a `FormBaseDetail`.
All other forms in the project are derived from `FormBaseList` or `FormBaseDetail`.
Now it seems that VS has huge problems with that, and my biggest problem is that VS keeps writing property values from the Ancestor form into the designer.cs from the child form.

for example, in `FormBaseList` I have this property/value :

```
this.gttDXGridView1.OptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow = true;
```

I expect that in a derived form, for example `FormClientList`, there is no mention for this value in the designer.cs, because it should fetch the value from its parent. In other words, just plain simple basic OOP.
And I also expect that when I change the property in `FormClientList` to

```
this.gttDXGridView1.OptionsView.ShowAutoFilterRow = false;
```

that this is seen as an override from the baseclass.
However, VS keeps overwriting the property in `FormClientList.Designer.cs` with the value found in `FormBaseList.Designer.cs`.
This breaks the rules of OOP in my opinion, other tools that support Visual Inheritance like Delphi for example do this correct.

How can I stop VS from doing this ?
The properties are changed using the designer.
All controls are DevExpress controls, or derived from a DevExpress control.

**Another example**, which works just opposite so its very strange.

For example put a Button on the BaseForm and give it an image.
The button with the image appears on all derived forms.
Now change the image on the button of the BaseForm.
You would expect the image to change on all derived forms also, but that does not happen.
I discovered that again VS has written the property value of the button in all derived designer.cs files, and this time it does not overwrites them.

Comment: There is no mechanism built into VS to do this.  DevExpress is the kind of control supplier that is likely to include their own code-serializer in their control designer.   You ought to ask them.

Comment: @HansPassant OK I will, at least I know already this now it narrows my search

Comment: Your *Another example* → I cannot confirm that. When you have a button having an image in the base form, if you change the image of the button in base form and rebuild the project, the button in derived form will show the new image. (Unless you have changed the image of the button in a derived form.)

Comment: First of all, Visual Inheritance on Winforms is not really friendly, if you can avoid it, just avoid it. I know it look sometime to be a great idea on the paper but... My only advice to avoid most of the issue is to ensure that all child form are closed when editing/updating the base form and to build the project after any modification of the base form before opening the child again. Hope it will help you.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Well VS has written the property value for the image in all derived Desinger.cs files, so that counts as changing it on the derived forms I guess. The problem is that VS should not have done that in the first place

Comment: @MarcoGuignard Yes I found that out the hard way that VS is no friend of Visual Inheritance. I am used to working in Delphi where this works very well, so I just applied the same idea to winforms...

Comment: @GuidoG It doesn't do. In derived form, it serializes just changed properties. Arrange a really simple test, without any 3rd party controls in a new project to see the behavior. Make sure after each change on base form, you build the project. Without a really simple and clean test, you may have inaccurate/incorrect observation which leads you to a wrong direction.

Comment: @RezaAghaei Well HansPassant already pointed that out and he thinks that DevExpress might be the responsible one here, not VS. I did not say that proper in my prior comment, sorry about that

Comment: @HansPassant It seems you where right, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I created a ticket about this at the DevExpress forum, and they where able to reproduce it.
It is now passed on to their developers.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T692940/devexpress-controls-break-visual-inheritance-in-visual-studio

It also seems I was not the first to report a similar problem.

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T692244/imageoptions-are-serialized-in-a-successor-when-visual-inheritance-is-in-effect